# How to redirect/forward context path in AWS ALB listener rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We have an AWS ALB with target groups. We are able to achieve context path redirect/forward using nginx. Now we want to redirect/forward queries for `path A` to `path B` below using listener rules. Please suggest how to achieve this.

`path A` -> internal-alb-599528282.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/**images**/5010/2352-5010.jpeg

`path B` -> internal-alb-599528282.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/**docimg**/5010/2352-5010.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "http_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "redirect"
    redirect {
      protocol       = "HTTP"
      port           = "80"
      status_code    = "HTTP_301"
      path           = "/new-path"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "http_listener_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http_listener.arn
  priority     = 100
  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn
  }
  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/old-path/*"]`enter code here`
    }
  }
}
```